# Linq InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In this code:

```
public static void Seed(IConfiguration configuration,
        ForumDbContext dbContext,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        if (dbContext.Users.Count()==0) 
CreateUsers(configuration, dbContext, roleManager, userManager)
                    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        
    }
```

I get a runtime exception on the line: `if (dbContext.Users.Count()==0)`
that is:

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EnumerableMethods' threw an exception.'
InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element

My DBContext code is as following:

```
public class ForumDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ForumDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().ToTable("Topics");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>().ToTable("Attachments");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>().ToTable("Subscriptions");
    }

    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

My User class is defined as follows:

```
public class User:IdentityUser
    {
        public string Discriminator { get; set; } = "User";
        public string Country { get; set; } = "";
        public string Signature { get; set; } = "";
        public bool IncludeSignature { get; set; } = true;

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool SignatureFormatted = false;
        

        [NotMapped]
        public int NrPosts { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This exception is thrown when a `Single()` call encounters more than one element. It seems unlikely that `dbContext.Users.Count()` is the source of the exception. What's the stack trace? And which EF version is this?

Comment: The stack trace says: external code. the version of EF I am using is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore       {3.1.9}.
I got this error when I switched the project to compile under .Net 6.0

Answer (score 2):

Updating the entityframework packages to the latest version solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little info to @user1238784's response:

It appears that Entity Framework versions and .NET releases are more closely tied than expected, especially since mismatched versions compile together just fine. Here's the proper version line up (with the Entity Framework branding changes and ASP.NET releases for reference):

- .NET Core 3.1 → EF Core 3.1 → ASP.NET Core 3.1
- .NET 5 → EF Core 5.0 → ASP.NET Core 5.0
- .NET 6 → EF Core 6.0 or EF7 or EF8 (while in preview) → ASP.NET Core 6.0
- .NET 7 → EF7 or EF8 (while in preview) → ASP.NET Core 7.0
- .NET 8 (preview) → no EF targeting → ASP.NET Core 8 (preview)
- .NET 8 → EF8 → ASP.NET Core 8